# undefined method `ordinalize' for 3:Fixnum (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I am trying to format a date like `Thu, 10th Jan 2016`. I wrote a method to take the current time, and make it appear as in the said format.

```
def time_format(ob_created_at)
  ob_duplicate = ob_created_at
  ob_duplicate = ob_created_at.strftime("%a")
  day = ob_created_at.strftime("%d")
  day = day.to_i.ordinalize
  ob_duplicate = ob_duplicate + day +  ob_created_at.strftime("%b %Y")
 end

t = Time.now
time_format(t)
```

`day` is string. I tried to converted to int, and apply `ordinalize` on it. It raises an undefined method error.

Comment: I don't see any method named `ordinalize` for `Fixnum`.

Comment: can you check the last but one line in the time_format method

Comment: In the line `day = day.to_i.ordinalize`, where did the method `ordinalize` come from?

Comment: Can you please tell me what is wrong with that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fixnum#ordinalize` is NOT in the ruby core lib. See [Ruby Doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html).

`Fixnum#ordinalize` is part of **Active Support** which is a dependency of Rails, so you can use this method in Rails application for free, but in non-rails projects, you have to install Active Support and require at least `active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections` to get access to it.

Answer (score 8):

[`ordinalize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-ordinalize) is not a Ruby method, but it is a method provided by Rails' `ActiveSupport` gem.

I would argue that it is not worth it to add a dependency to the `ActiveSupport` gem to your project when all you need is just a simple method. Find its implementation [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb#L336), please also note the `ordinal` above.

All you need are these two methods:

```
def ordinal(number)
  abs_number = number.to_i.abs

  if (11..13).include?(abs_number % 100)
    "th"
  else
    case abs_number % 10
      when 1; "st"
      when 2; "nd"
      when 3; "rd"
      else    "th"
    end
  end
end

def ordinalize(number)
  "#{number}#{ordinal(number)}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I don't know why other people are not so compassionate

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once.  I have been battling ActiveSupport for literally days just for this one method.